# TCL/TK in browser

Tags: tcl, port, tk-toolkit

I've been trying to run a TCL/TK script in a browser so people with minimal computer knowledge can run it (my script) on all devices.

I've come across the TCL/TK plugin from 2006 but I can't get it to work. Even if I could, it doesn't contain the user friendliness I am looking for.
I also came across a website that runs TCL scripts in-browser but doesn't seem to recognise TK commands....
So far to distribute it to people I wrapped it into a .exe but people are requesting it to be used on mobile devices (with more mobility than a windows laptop).

Any one got some information to do this without rewriting all of my code?
Or an easy way to port a TCL/TK script to iPhone/iPad or Android (I don't think there will be any easy solution for this, that is why the browser concept made most sense to me)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the browser plugin depends on the browser supporting the [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) specification, and that's now been largely removed from browsers (and was never supported on mobile devices). This has irritated quite a few other people too, and I don't think there's much you can do to fix it directly. So instead, let's look at some workarounds…

You might be able to use the [NaCl support](http://wiki.tcl.tk/_natcl/index.html) in Chrome on desktop systems, or you could package things up in a [starpack](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3663) (ActiveState's [TDK](http://www.activestate.com/tcl-dev-kit) is a commercial version of that, among other things) and for deployment to Android you can use [Androwish](http://www.androwish.org/index.html/home) (which I personally recommend). I'm nothing like as certain about solutions for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For plain Tcl try [EmTcl](http://aidanhs.github.io/emtcl/), Tcl compiled with emscripten.